# Map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}),L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ is continuous under certain operator topologies

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

Consider the map $$ \Lambda: \mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{L}(L^2(\mathbb{R}),L^2(\mathbb{R})) =: \mathcal{L}$$ defined by $\Lambda(s)(f)(x) = (1+x^2)^{is/2}f(x)$ where $f\in L^2$ and $s,x\in\mathbb{R}$. Recall that $\mathcal{L}$ has the norm topology (also called the uniform operator topology), but it also was the weak and strong operator topologies, defined as follows:

- The former is the weakest one such that all the maps $\mathcal{L}\to\mathbb{C}$, defined via $T \mapsto \ell(Tf)$, are continuous (where $\ell\in(L^2)^*,f\in L^2$ are arbitrary).
- The latter is the weakest one such that all the maps $\mathcal{L}\to L^2$, defined via $T\mapsto Tf$, are continuous (where $f\in L^2$ is arbitrary).

How can we determine if $\Lambda$ is continuous w.r.t. each of these three topologies? Letting $h_s(x):= (1+x^2)^{is/2}$, I think that continuity wrt the uniform, strong, and weak topolgies (respectively) is equivalent to:

- If $s\in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed, then as $t\to s$ we have $\int_\mathbb{R} |f|^2|h_s-h_t|^2\to 0$ where $f$ is allowed to depend on $t$. Rigorously, $\lim_{t\to s}\sup_{f\in L^2}\int_\mathbb{R}|f|^2 |h_s-h_t|^2 =0$.
- The same statement as above, but now $f$ is fixed as $t\to s$.
- If $s\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed and $j\in L^1$ is fixed, then as $t\to s$ we have $\int_\mathbb{R} (h_s-h_t)\cdot j \to 0$.

All three are eluding me for the moment, unfortunately. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the strong operator topology, use the dominated convergence theorem. For the operator norm, try to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim it is not continuous wrt the norm topology, but it is continuous wrt the other two (it suffices to prove this for the strong operator topology). If $\Lambda$ were continuous wrt the uniform operator topology, then by definition $\forall s\in\mathbb{R}$ we'd have $$\lim_{t\to s} ||  \Lambda_s-\Lambda_t||_{L^2\to L^2} = 0.$$ Notice $\Lambda_s-\Lambda_t$ is simply a multiplication operator, that multiplies by $h_s-h_t$. We claim that this implies its operator norm equals $||h_s-h_t||_{\infty}$. This is a general fact: if $M: L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ multiplies by some function $m$, then $||M||=||m||_\infty$. Indeed, $||M||\le ||m||_\infty$ is obvious and for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a nonzero $f$ supported on $\{ |m| > ||m||_\infty-\epsilon\}$, so $||Mf||_2 \ge (||m||_\infty-\epsilon)||f||_2$ so $||M||\ge ||m||_\infty-\epsilon$. This means that $||\Lambda_s-\Lambda_t|| = ||h_s-h_t||_\infty = \sup_x (1+x^2)^{is/2} - (1+x^2)^{it/2}=2$, which is easy to verify (by setting $\xi=\log(1+x^2)$, which can be any positive real number, and solving $\xi = \frac{\pi(4n)}{s} = \frac{\pi(4n+2+\epsilon)}{t}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon\ge 0$ really small. This makes $h_s(x)=1$ and $h_t(x)\approx -1$). Thus the above limit is in fact 2!

To see continuity wrt the strong operator norm, we claim it suffices to prove that all the compositions $$ \mathbb{R}\overset\Lambda\longrightarrow \mathcal{L} \overset{\text{ev}_f}\longrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$$ are continuous, for any fixed $f\in L^2$, where $\text{ev}_f$ is the evaluation map at $f$. This is because the strong operator topology is the coarsest one such that all these evaluation maps are continuous. (And if the above compisitions were continuous, then $\Lambda^{-1}(U)$ is open for any $U\subset\mathcal{L}$ of the form $U=\text{ev}_f^{-1}(V)$ and $V\subset L^2$ open, but these $U$'s generate the strong operator topology and so $\Lambda^{-1}(U)$ must be open for any $U$). The above compositions simply take $s\mapsto h_sf$. So we must prove 
$$ \lim_{t\to s} \int_\mathbb{R} |f|^2|h_s-h_t|^2 =0,$$ with $f\in L^2$ fixed. It suffices to take a sequence $t_n\to s$. Notice $|h_s-h_{t_n}|^2\le 4$ and so the functions $g_n := |f|^2|h_s-h_{t_n}|^2$ are dominated by $4|f|^2\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, $g_n\to 0$ pointwise because for any $x$, $\lim_{t\to s} h_t(x)=h_s(x)$. Hence, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\mathbb{R} g_n = \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n = \int_\mathbb{R} 0 = 0,$$ as desired (where the second $\lim$ denotes the pointwise limit).